# ngrok command not found and is already on /usr/local/bin

Tags: macos, localhost, ngrok, tunnel

I'm trying to install ngrok on my mac. Here is what I have done so far.

- Downloaded ngrok from here https://ngrok.com/download.
- Unziped the file and copied the Unix Executable File into `/usr/local/bin` like many other questions and answers suggested.

Now when I try to execute any command with ngrok in the current folder or in the project one the result of this is `command not found` but ngrok is there as you can see.

[image]

By the way, here is the path:

```sh
ramonmorcillo@Ramons-MacBook-Pro bin % echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

I may be missing something but I have been all morning searching for an answer and followed all other questions steps but it is still not working. Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it. I connected my account and it worked.

```sh
ramonmorcillo@Ramons-MacBook-Pro bin % ./ngrok authtoken MY _AUTH_TOKEN
Authtoken saved to configuration file: /Users/ramonmorcillo/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml
ramonmorcillo@Ramons-MacBook-Pro bin %  ./ngrok help
NAME:
   ngrok - tunnel local ports to public URLs and inspect traffic

DESCRIPTION:
    ngrok exposes local networked services behinds NATs and firewalls to the
    public internet over a secure tunnel. Share local websites, build/test
    webhook consumers and self-host personal services.
    
...
```

Comment: You are not answering your question neither are you giving ideas to get the result you are sharing

Comment: Hi there @Anjayluh, thanks for telling me this, I didn't know this was not clear when I answered it a year ago. As you may think I have already lost some context from the issue, however, as far as I understand by my answer, it looks like using an auth token to connect my account to ngrok was the solution. Hope this helps you :)